# Can't figure out the correct amount of bits for an output

Tags: verilog

Well, my task is to create a n(n is a multiple of 4) bit cla (carry lookahead adder) using 4 bit cla and multiplexers. Specifically, I have to implement the following:
[image]

The part that is in brackets has to be repeated as many times as need for the parameter n that is given. My Question is: how should I define the wires r,t and c?
At first I thought the following:

```
wire [3n/4-3-1:0] c; // without considering the first wire that comes out of the right most cla4
wire [n - 4 - 1:0] r,t;
```

This does indeed work for n>4 (8,12,16...) but there is an obvious problem when n=4 ([-1:0]).
Is there a way I can get around this? One simple solution would be to have these wires be more bits that needed, but I am stuck trying to think of another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
localparam M = (N>4) ? (3*N)/4 - 3 : 1;
localparam L = (N>4) ? N-4 : 1;

wire [M-1:0] c;
wire [L-1:0] r,t;
```